# Java 8 to 11 Upgrade powermock issue

Tags: java, java-8, jvm, powermock, java-11

I'm getting the following error when I try to upgrade java 8 to 11

java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class jdk.internal.reflect.ConstructorAccessorImpl loaded by org.powermock.core.classloader.MockClassLoade

If I use the following annotation in my test case, it will pass.
@PowerMockIgnore("jdk.internal.reflect.*")

But, the above error will be thrown as a warning.

How can I use the following JVM option to resolve this? Can I only use JVM option without annotation?

--add-opens java.base/jdk.internal.reflect=ALL-UNNAMED